# Bad JSON formatting after parsing XML feed using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, json, simplexml

I'm parsing an XML feed, and attempting to create JSON output. I can't seem to figure out why my JSON formatting is off. This is the code I'm using to loop through the XML feed, parse it, and build JSON output:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($myxmlfeed, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

foreach ($xml->{'xml-node-name'} as $article)
{
  $tmp = array(
            "title" => $article->title,
            "image" => null,
            "resource" => array(
                    "articleLink" => $site)
            );
  array_push($array, $tmp);
  unset($tmp);
}
```

This is the output:

```
[
 {
   "title":{
     "0":"This is my article title"
   },
   "image":null,
   "resource":{
     "articleLink":"http://www.website.com/link.html"
   }
 }
]
```

However, this is the output format I need:

```
[
 {
   "title":"This is my article title",
   "image":null,
   "resource":{
     "articleLink":"http://www.website.com/link.html"
   }
 }
]
```

Why is the "title" being added as a key/value pair?

Comment: No idea without seeing the xml, but you can fix: `"title" => $article->title[0],`

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that `$article->title` is an array, not a string as you desire. A sample of the XML would help us explain why, but in the mean time you need to be accessing element 0 of that array:

```
$tmp = array(
    "title" => $article->title[0],
    "image" => null,
    "resource" => array(
        "articleLink" => $site
    )
);
```

Comment: It seems @Steve beat me, though he did so in the comments. If he moves his comment to an answer, you should accept it.

Comment: Thank you both! I was able to resolve the problem by casting to a string.... "title" => (string)$article->title